# How to propertly extend from superclass

Tags: java

I am totally new to java and tried to create a simple command line application but I am doing smth so wrong and I am not realizing it. Here's my code

```
public class Auto1 {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int value;
    private int soldPrice;
    private int year;
    private int hp;


    public Auto1(String make, String model, int value, int soldPrice, int year, int hp) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.value = value;
        this.soldPrice= soldPrice;
        this.year = year;
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    public void setMake(String a) {
        make = a;
    }
    public void setModel(String b) {
        model = b;
    }
    public void setvalue(int c) {
        value = c;
    }
    public void setSoldPrice(int d) {
        soldPrice = d;
    }
    public void setYear(int e) {
        year = e;
    }
    public void setHp(int f) {
        hp = f;
    }
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public int getSoldPrice() {
        return soldPrice;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void price() {
        int price = value - soldPrice;
        if(a >=5000) {
            System.out.println("You Overpaid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fair Price");
        }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to create a subclass in which I would create this code

```
public class Auto extends Auto1{
     Auto1 auto;
     public auto = ("Audi","R8",162900,200000,2017,610){}
}
```

However it is not allowing me because "public" is an illegal start of type apparently and I don't know how else to create an object. Sorry if this sounds stupid to anyone but I'm very new to Java.

Comment: That's not valid Java. Are you going for is-a or has-a relationship? What's your goal?

Comment: I don't really know what those are...I am really new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `public auto = ("Audi","R8",162900,200000,2017,610){}` is not valid Java syntax. Did you mean to put this in your constructor? It looks like your class `Auto` is a more specific version than `Auto1`, namely one that refers to a specific "kind" of `Auto1`.

```
public Auto()
{
    super("Audi","R8",162900,200000,2017,610);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this out. One more problem tho...how to I initialize this application.  What do I need to write in the main class?

Comment: To construct a new class, call `Auto a = new Auto();` and do whatever with the object

Comment: how do I initialize the application with the given values of this class ,Andrew

Comment: To correct, you construct a new object, not class. When you create a new `Auto` you call the superclass constructor and give the values to the superclass.

Comment: we might not be on the same page and it's due to the fact that I am new.

Comment: here's what I did public class Auto extends Auto1 {
  
    
    public Auto()
{
    super("Audi","R8",162900,200000,2017,610);
}

}

Comment: where to put the main class and how to initiate it with these values,sorry for commenting many times but I had no idea "enter" ket adds the comment instead of creating a new line

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer to your question, but what you are trying to do looks like a not necessarily the best OO design. 
By the look of it, your Auto1 should extend your Auto class (i.e. other way around), as it is (in theory) more specific. In this case, depends on what you are doing, you may want make Auto an abstract class. 
If your Auto1 is kind of the "real" car with wheels and engine and Auto1 is just some model info, it is much better idea not to extend Auto1, but to have a Auto1 type variable in Auto class. In this case make sure you really want to make it "settable", in theory, once the car (object of Auto type) is created, it should not change properties like make and year.